# Why I can't use subs with sympy? // 'list' object has no attribute 'subs'

Tags: python, math, sympy

I Want to substitute x to the var that the user user insert

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')

xi =int(input("insert initial x: "))
funcion = input("Insert the function: ")

def fx(funcion,x):
    return solve(funcion,x, implicit=true))


despejada = fx(funcion,x)
print(despejada.subs({x:xi)
```

I insert:

> 10

> x+10

I get:

```
weass.py", line 13, in <module>
print(despejada.subs({x:xi})) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

Why I can't use **subs** with sympy?

Comment: `despejada` is a list, not a sympy expression.  Read and learn from the error message!

Comment: Try `despejada[0].subs({x:xi})`.

Comment: Ty @OscarBenjamin and hpaulj 
I hope someone write it as an answer so I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, the solve function returns a list of the different solutions (here it contains 1 element). You need to use a subscript (with brackets) to refer to a single solution.

```
despejada[0].subs({x:xi})
```

As an additional tip: unless you are importing stuff from your own package that you know everything about, avoid using `from sympy import *` as it clutters your namespace. Prefer using something like `import sympy as sp` as you are doing with numpy. It can save you some headaches down the line.